# Updating React child component after state change

Tags: reactjs

I made a text input box which, when submitted, will update the state of the messages in the parent component.  The messages in the parent component are passed down to the message display.  I'd like the component responsible for displaying the messages to update and display the messages after each submission, but can't figure out how to do it.  I made a code sandbox here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-pasteur-nz32o

Here's my code:

Parent component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Messages from "./Messages";
import Input from "./Input";

export default class Container extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      messages: []
    };
  }

  updateMessage(message) {
    this.state.messages.push(message);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Messages messages={this.state.messages} />
        <Input updateMessage={message => this.updateMessage(message)} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Message input component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Input extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      message: ""
    };
 }

  sendMessage() {
    this.props.updateMessage(this.state.message);
    this.setState({ message: "" });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.message}
          onChange={({ target }) => {
            this.setState({ message: target.value });
          }}
        />
        <button onClick={() => this.sendMessage()}>Send</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Message display component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Messages extends Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.messages.map(message => {
      return <div>{message}</div>;
    });
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your code:

```
updateMessage(message) {
  this.state.messages.push(message);
}
```

You're modifying the state directly and [you're not supposed to do that](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly) (except for in the constructor). It won't cause a re-render in this way. Instead, clone the state, modify it, then update the state via [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). Calling `setState` will invoke a re-render.

```
updateMessage(message) {
  this.setState({
    messages: [...this.state.messages, message],
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your `updateMessage(message)` method, can you try:

```
updateMessage(message) {
    let { messages } = this.state;
    messages.push(message)
    this.setState({ messages })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked.  Why does it update when you write it like that?

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5/

Answer (score 1):

**Your error is in this part**

```
updateMessage(message) {
    this.state.messages.push(message);
  }
```

**You can not change state directly. You must use setState() method to change state**

```
updateMessage(message) {
        this.setState({
             messages : [...this.state.messages, message]
        });
      }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `this.setState({ messages: [...this.state.messages, message] })`